# NullpointerException error in android gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, android-adapter

I have to develop an one android application.

Here  i have to create custom gridview adapter class.

But am getting following error:

```
      06-14 14:56:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(797): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     06-14 14:56:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(797):     at        com.bestinuk.adapter.CategoriesAdapter.getCount(CategoriesAdapter.java:34)
   06-14 14:56:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(797):   at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:180)
    06-14 14:56:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.example.androidbestinuk.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:43)
```

i have wrote the adapter class like below:

```
  public class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
```

List categories;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

```
public CategoriesAdapter(Activity a, List<Category> categories) {
    activity = a;
   this.categories=categories;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return categories.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.categoryimage);
    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.categorytitle); // title


    Category categorylist = (Category) getItem(position);

    title.setText(categorylist.getmCategoryName());




    thumb_image.setImageBitmap(categorylist.getmCategoryImage());

    return vi;
   }
    }
```

Here why am getting abovr error ???

How can i resolve these error ???

please give me solution for these ???

**EDIT:**

yes my list is null.That's why am getting null pointer exception.

this is my HomePage.java class:

```
  public class HomePage extends Activity {

      List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();;
          GridView category_list;
            CategoriesAdapter categoryViewAdapter;
          private ProgressDialog pDialog;
           static final String URL = "http://dev.mercuryminds.com/xctesting/feed.xml";

           /** Called when the activity is first created. */
              @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.main);

              category_list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.categorylist);

               GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
             task.execute(new String[] { URL });

                }



            //private inner class extending AsyncTask
           private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
                private Activity context;
             public GetXMLTask(Activity context) {
                  this.context = context;

             } 
             @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressbar
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomePage.this);
            // Set progressbar title
            pDialog.setTitle("BestinUk");
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();
                    }
                @Override
            protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {
                Document dom = null;
                String xml = null;
                for (String url : urls) {
                    xml = getXmlFromUrl("http://dev.mercuryminds.com/xctesting/feed.xml");
                    dom= XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
                    }
                return dom;
            }

                @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Document dom) {

    Category categoryBean = null;

                if(dom !=null) {
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList categoryNL = root.getElementsByTagName("Category");
            if(categoryNL.getLength() > 0){
                for (int i=0;i<categoryNL.getLength();i++){
                    Node categoryNode = categoryNL.item(i);
                    Element categoryElmt = null;
                    if(categoryNode.hasAttributes()){
                        categoryBean = new Category();

                        categoryElmt = (Element)categoryNode;
                        categoryBean.setmCategoryName(categoryElmt.getAttribute("title"));
                        categoryBean.setmCategoryID(Integer.parseInt(categoryElmt.getAttribute("categoryid")));
                        categoryBean.setmCategoryImageLink(categoryElmt.getAttribute("image"));
   categories.add(categoryBean);
                        categoryViewAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(HomePage.this, categories);

                        category_list.setAdapter(categoryViewAdapter);
                        System.out.println("Category Title is "+ " "+categoryElmt.getAttribute("title"));
                        System.out.println("Category Image is "+ " "+categoryElmt.getAttribute("image"));
                    }

        -----------
        ------------
          ---------
               pDialog.dismiss();
            }

           }
```

Now am getting following error:

```
06-14 16:00:21.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 16:00:21.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1305): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.example.androidbestinuk.Category
   06-14 16:00:21.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1305):  at com.bestinuk.adapter.CategoriesAdapter.getView(CategoriesAdapter.java:56)
```

This is my 56th line:

```
 Category categorylist = (Category) getItem(position);
```

what's wrong in my code ??? please give me solution ???

i got the output after add the below line:

```
 Category categorylist = categories.get(position);
```

Comment: May be your `categories` is not being set with an instance in your constructor. Who is creating the instance of `CategoriesAdapter` ?

Comment: check xml ids in `R.layout.list_item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is wrong:

```
categoryViewAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(HomePage.this, categories);
category_list.setAdapter(categoryViewAdapter);
```

Try to first fill the list in the for loop and construct the adapter after the list is being filled.

EDIT:

```
for (int i=0;i<categoryNL.getLength();i++){
                Node categoryNode = categoryNL.item(i);
                Element categoryElmt = null;
                if(categoryNode.hasAttributes()) {
                    categoryBean = new Category();

                    categoryElmt = (Element)categoryNode;
                    categoryBean.setmCategoryName(categoryElmt.getAttribute("title"));
                    categoryBean.setmCategoryID(Integer.parseInt(categoryElmt.getAttribute("categoryid")));
                    categoryBean.setmCategoryImageLink(categoryElmt.getAttribute("image"));

                    //add to the categories
                    categories.add(categoryBean);

                    System.out.println("Category Title is "+ " "+categoryElmt.getAttribute("title"));
                    System.out.println("Category Image is "+ " "+categoryElmt.getAttribute("image"));
                }
}

//add the categories to the category adapter
categoryViewAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(HomePage.this, categories);

                    category_list.setAdapter(categoryViewAdapter);
```

of course you should whether the categories is initialized and not null!

EDIT:

in your adapter you are overriding `getItem(int position)` and returning `position` instead return the actual `Category` object from the list that you are passing as a parameter

Comment: yes i know the concept..but i didn't write the code programmatically.please give me the solution for how can i add the categoryBean on list ???

Comment: check the last edit it should solve the problem that you are facing right now

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**You can use add() to add contents in your List.

--
change

```
private List<Category> categories;
```

to

```
private List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
```

(Sorry, List cannot be instantiated, because it is an interface)

Comment: Then why to use the constructor to set the `List` ?

Comment: no this is not the way because it is already initialized in constructor

Comment: The error says `06-14 14:56:26.676: E/AndroidRuntime(797):     at        com.bestinuk.adapter.CategoriesAdapter.getCount(CategoriesAdapter.java:34)`
which means in getCount() categories is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

this error means your categories list is null

check your code where you new the CategoriesAdapter whether your categories param is null

Answer (score 0):

Just because maybe you call it with a null list...

```
public int getCount() {
    if(categories != null)
    return categories.size();
    return 0;
}
```